# Getting 303 for some courses when getting course TOC

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I am trying to get the course contents by making this call:

```
/d2l/api/le/1.4/295354/content/toc
```

This call returns a 303 error.  Using the SDK, the error shown is:
Error: Unknown error occured (HTTP status 303)
The raw response in Fiddler shows it as:
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

This call to another course works fine:

```
/d2l/api/le/1.4/110541/content/toc
```

It returns the expected json.  And Fiddler shows it a HTTP/1.1 200 OK.

I thought maybe it was a permission problem, but I am making the call as a Super Admin.  I also tried using an account that is a course admin, but it didn't make any difference.  Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Does the back-end service's system log show any exceptions around the call of any kind? I presume it's a repeatable error? Is the user's enrollment in both courses exactly the same (either enrolled via cascading enrollment in both, or explicitly enrolled in both)?

With this particular call, if it makes it down to the service layer in the back-end, then it can only return a 403 or a 200; even if you had no TOC (because no root module(s)), then the call should return an empty list. If you received a 400, then this indicates a fault somewhere higher up the call stack. Are you sure the org unit actually exists? Can you get back the properties for the org unit in question via API?

This seems most mysterious, and I'd be tempted to recommend you open a support incident with the D2L support organization (via your approved support contact, or account manager) to pursue this as a potential defect if you are absolutely sure you can't find a problem in your own calling code.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check the back-end service's system log.  I'm looking for help from our system admins on that.   Yes, it is repeatable, happens every time.  I assume the enrollment is the same.  I'm user a super admin account.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that the org unit exists.  Here are the results from a few API calls.
`/d2l/api/le/1.4/295354/content/toc  -- Unknown error occured (HTTP status 303)`

`/d2l/api/lp/1.4/courses/295354  --  Success (HTTP status 200)`

`/d2l/api/le/1.4/329302/content/toc  --  Success (HTTP status 200)`

`/d2l/api/lp/1.4/courses/329302  --  Success (HTTP status 200)`

Comment: There aren't any Valence errors in the system log that I can see.

Comment: With the help of our admin I was able get a detailed error message from the log:
`ExceptionMessage`
`Unable to resolve url for topic 2299923`

Comment: Interesting. This would seem to indicate that part of the process of generating the TOC for the original call is going through the module structure of the course, and building it up -- it appears that one of the content topics in your structure (id 2299923) has an unresolvable URL property, and this seems to be causing the problem on the contents call. You could try fetching that content topic by ID with the API and see what happens; you could also try manually investigating that content topic in the Web UI and try to fix the URL property?

Comment: The exception message you're reporting does indeed seem to belong to the part of the implementation that creates the topic structure attached to a module, for the purposes of building out the table of contents it will send back. The work around here might be to investigate that particular content topic's URL property and see if you can give it a resolvable URL through the Web UI -- it's not clear to me how that topic would have been given an unresolvable URL in the first place.

Comment: You may want to report this to D2L's support desk as a defect via your approved support contact, or account/partner manager. At the least, this may be an inappropriate error occuring; it's also possible that this error state is unintentionally affecting the TOC call (i.e. even if the URL for a topic can't be resolved, that shouldn't stop the construction of the TOC structure).

Comment: Thanks again, Viktor.  We have a ticket with the D2L support desk.

Comment: This is a Known Issue, a fix for this issue has been made available in 10.4.8 (onwards).